# What does the Google GIN method : bind(Class class)

Tags: gwt, bind, gwt-gin

I've read some documentation and downloaded samples but I still got a question.
In most sample, the GIN module uses something like :

```
bind(MainActivityMapper.class);
bind(VerticalMasterActivityMapper.class);
```

I don't understand what it does? If I remove it from the sample code, everything works perfectly.

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 1):

Someone pointed me to the GUICE page : http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html

There is no reason for it to be different in Gin.

Here is what it says for this particular case :

> This statement does essentially nothing; it "binds the 
>   class to itself" and does not change Guice's default behavior. You may
>   still want to use this if you prefer your Module class to serve as an
>   explicit manifest for the services it provides. Also, in rare cases,
>   Guice may be unable to validate a binding at injector creation time
>   unless it is given explicitly.

Note: I'm not sure wether or not I should Accept my own answer, so I'll leave it as is.